# employee daily sales submission form with respect to ID

Tags: php, mysql

After login, an employee has to update his daily product sales. For the purpose I have made 02 tables named registration and dailysales. Table registration verifies the userID and password for login of user and has link to enter daily sales in 'dailysales' table. How can I insert the userID of logged-in user from table 'registration' to table 'dailysales' automatically. Note: In Table 'dailysales' employee also has to put daily sales of products from html form. In below coding how can i add userID and user Name of logged-in user automatically alongwith entry of products.

coding for dailysales is as under:-

```
<?php
require('config.php');

//Start the Session
session_start();

if((isset($_POST['diaper']) && !empty($_POST['diaper']))
&& (isset($_POST['babylotion']) && !empty($_POST['babylotion']))
&& (isset($_POST['nfacewash']) && !empty($_POST['nfacewash']))
&& (isset($_POST['facewash']) && !empty($_POST['facewash']))
&& (isset($_POST['hremover']) && !empty($_POST['hremover']))){
$Diaper = $_POST ['diaper'];
$BabyLotion = $_POST ['babylotion'];
$Neem_fw = $_POST ['nfacewash'];
$Facewash = $_POST ['facewash'];
$Hair_remover = $_POST ['hremover'];
}
$sql= "INSERT INTO dailyrecord (babydiaper,babylotion,hairremover,neemfw,neetfw) VALUES ('$Diaper','$BabyLotion','$Neem_fw','$Facewash','$Hair_remover')";

if (mysqli_query ($connection, $sql)){
    echo '<script>alert("Congratulations! You Have Successfully added your sale!");</script>';
    }
else{
        echo '<script>alert("Sorry! Please fill the fields marked with *!");</script>';


    }

?>
```

Coding for login is as under:-

```
<?php  

//Start the Session
session_start();
require('config.php');

// If the form is submitted or not.
// If the form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['id']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
// Assigning posted values to variables.
$E_id = $_POST['id'];
$P_word = $_POST['password'];

// Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["id"]))){
        $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
    } else{
        $U_name = trim($_POST["id"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
        $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
    } else{
        $P_word = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

// Checking the values are existing in the database or not
$query = "SELECT * FROM registeration WHERE employee_id='$E_id' and password='$P_word'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['id'] = $E_id;
}else{
//If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
$fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
}
//if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
$E_id = $_SESSION['id'];
echo "<center><table border='2' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid #6699FF;color:#000000;width:60%'>
<tr>
<th>Distributor</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>Visiting Area</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr\t\t\t>";
echo "<td>" . $row['emp_name'] . "&nbsp". $row['f_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['designation'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['varea'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</center></table>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else{

echo '<center>Invalied Username or Password</center>';
}
?>
```

Comment: does this have anything to do with `sql-server` or is this just simply mysql? Also, your question refers to `dailysales` but the sql suggests the table is called `dailyrecord`

Answer (score 0):

In your daily sales code, you can use the `$_SESSION['id']` to get the id

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
```

So you can use it in your `$sql`. You need to create a column `id` in your `dailyrecord` table with foreign key to your `registeration` table (so both id's are equal)

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO dailyrecord (id,babydiaper,babylotion,hairremover,neemfw,neetfw) VALUES ($id,'$Diaper','$BabyLotion','$Neem_fw','$Facewash','$Hair_remover')";
```

Anyways, you should use prepared statements to avoid sql injection for your $sql

Comment: I have used your suggestion. but after adding $id=$_SESSION['id']; and $sql statement, it is inserting all data in to table but id under id column its not showing id of logged-in user. it is showing 0. Help please!

Comment: If your id it's a integer value, you should remove the quotation marks for the id in **VALUES ('$id','$Diaper',**. It should be **VALUES ($id,'$Diaper',**

Comment: Actually where to put $id=$_SESSION['id']; in my code? May I put it right after session_start()? or in if statement block or after if statement. Because I have put $id=$_SESSION['id']; right after session_start (); and removing quotation marks it gives 'Sorry! Please fill the fields marked with *!' which is else portion of if (mysqli_query ($connection, $sql)). This mean after removing quotation marks $sql is not functioning.

Comment: also i have added a foreign key like this ALTER TABLE `dailyrecord`
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_employee_id
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id)
    REFERENCES `registeration`(employee_id);

Answer (score 0):

As the user only gets the opportunity to add a record after a successful login there is the session variable with his/her ID available to use for insertion into sales record. Assumed that the `dailyrecord` or `dailysales` table (?which?) has a column for the user ID called `employee_id` then you could try something like this.

```
<?php

    require('config.php');
    session_start();

    $babydiaper = !empty( $_POST['diaper'] ) ? $_POST['diaper'] : false;
    $babylotion = !empty( $_POST['babylotion'] ) ? $_POST['babylotion'] : false;
    $neemfw = !empty( $_POST['nfacewash'] ) ? $_POST['nfacewash'] : false;
    $neetfw = !empty( $_POST['facewash'] ) ? $_POST['facewash'] : false;
    $hairremover = !empty( $_POST['hremover'] ) ? $_POST['hremover'] : false;

    if( $babydiaper && $babylotion && $neemfw && $neetfw && $hairremover && isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ){

        $sql='insert into `dailyrecord` ( `employee_id`, `babydiaper`, `babylotion`, `hairremover`, `neemfw`, `neetfw` ) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)';
        $stmt=$connection->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            $id=$_SESSION['id'];
            $stmt->bind_param('isssss', $id, $babydiaper, $babylotion, $hairremover, $neemfw, $neetfw );

            $message = $stmt->execute() ? 'Congratulations - the sale was added' : 'Bogus - the sale could not be added';
            $stmt->close();
            $connection->close();


        } else {
            $message='Sorry - there was a database problem. Please contact the administrator';
        }
    } else {
        $message='One of more fields was empty...';
    }

    echo "<script>alert('$message');</script>";
?>
```

Comment: In  the query $sql='insert into `dailyrecord` ( `employee_id`, `babydiaper`, `babylotion`, `hairremover`, `neemfw`, `neetfw` ) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)'; is values remain like this (?,?,?,?,?,?). if not i know what to put for babydiaper, babylotion etc like $babydiaper, $babylotion.. but what to put against employee_id?

Comment: because when i am using this code as it is,.. it is given 'one of more fields was empty'..but if i am changing query to $sql= "INSERT INTO dailyrecord (employee_id,babydiaper,babylotion,hairremover,neemfw,neetfw) VALUES ('$Diaper','$BabyLotion','$Neem_fw','$Facewash','$Hair_remover')"; the result is same

Comment: The `?` is a placeholder within a `prepared statement` and should remain as `?` because by directly embedding variables within the SQL statement you open your code to sql injection attacks. The query in the comment above has too few parameters/variables which is why that failed... the first, as I mentioned in the answer, is assumed to be `employee_id`

Comment: As you have not shown the schema for your db I guessed at the name of the column ( employee_id )